# MongoDB java driver connection management

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, database

I have recently started learning `MongoDB` in `Java` and I found that I don't have to worry about closing connection per query just like we did for `Mysql` and other `sql database`.

I want to know, how well `MongoDB java driver` manage connection for every request? Did they take care it in java driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you mean by "designing a Java Driver". Mongo comes with its own java driver. I assume, you don't mean creating an alternative driver, but merely want to use an existing driver with MongoDB.

In this case, you don't really need to manage connections from within your application. Mongo Java Driver maintains a connection pool internally, so when you make, say, insert operation, it will fetch a connection from its internal pool, issue an insert action to MongoDB and close the connection.

According to [Mongo Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/), the Driver is thread safe. You should add some code in certain cases when you work with replica set and slaveOk option, but I assume you're talking about more basic cases.

You should create a single object of *MongoClient* object and use it in your application even when it's multi-threaded.
The only thing you need to do is call

```
mongoClient.close()
```

just before you dispose the instance of the driver.

A tutorial of what can be done with the Mongo java driver can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/)

Hope, this helps